# How to prevent button onClick firing repeatly?

Tags: android, button

I have a Button which sets both onLongClickListener & onClickListener :

onLongClickListener :

```
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            do something ...
                            return true;
                    }
```

onClickListener :

```
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            do something else ...
                    }
```

When I long click the button, onLongClick fires repeatly 
(sometimes onClick fires too when I release the button, it's weird @@")
What I want is to make the onLongClick be triggered only once for one long press.
So I modified the code :

onLongClickListener :

```
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            do something ...
                            myButton.setLongClickable(false);
                            return true;
                    }
```

onClickListener :

```
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            myButton.setLongClickable(true);
                            do something else ...
                    }
```

Unfortunately, the onClick callback was locked too after onLongClick fires!
I cant unlock the button anymore :|
Whats wrong with my code? Also, why onClick sometimes works when I release my button after a long click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the code you need, give me a minute to post it.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //DO STUFF GRAH!
        }
    });
    btn.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //OTHER STUFF
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This worked fine for me. I made an int and onLongClick added one and displayed it in a toast. Always incremented by one, and didn't do the onClick (reset it to 0).

Comment: Eclipse was taking it's time, sorry.

Comment: Actually it's 100% the same as my original code, but it still can not work on my emulator :|

Comment: What API level are you testing on? This worked perfectly on 2.2 for me.